# Regarding webservice with spring

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I was looking for an example of web service to add two numbers in CXF that I want to made through spring , Please advise urls which have shown the example of webservice through CXF on SOAP , so that I can convert and do it with spring itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good example how to write `CXF` web service with `Spring`:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

This one also refers to pretty good example:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pojo-springcxf/

This one also explains very clear what you need:

http://springinpractice.com/2008/02/29/web-services-with-spring-2-5-and-apache-cxf-2-0/